# Trying to switch image states - from still to animate - using giphy API

Tags: javascript, jquery, giphy-api

So I'm in a bootcamp, bout to begin the 7th week. We have an API assignment, and I chose to use the Giphy API. Okay, I've made the ajax call, have the json object, am displaying gifs with a button click. Once the gifs load, you should be able to make image animate, then upon next click, the image becomes still again.  the process should be able to repeat itself ad nauseam.  I have it set up the way that makes sense; however, I cant seem to get the urls to change upon click the way it's currently written. I tried .splice url, and using concat to complete updated url; however, I cant seem to figure out how to get the image to revert back to still state upon next click... been working on this for sooooo many hours, will someone please lend me a fresh set of eyes?

here's my js and jquery

```js
// $("#loadTimer, .buttonGallery, #btnGeneratingbtn").hide();
var topics = ["Brandon", "Biggie Smalls", "Dr. Seuss", "Paul McCartney", "John Lennon", "Will Ferrell", "Jimmy Fallon", "Chris Farley", "Dane Cook", "Eminem", "Nas", "Jay-Z", "Rakim", "William Shakespeare","Jim Morrison", "James Maynard", "Serj Tankian"];
var gifcount = 0;
var gifLocation;
var clickCount = 0;

var buttonFactory = function() {
    $(".buttonGallery").empty();

    for (i = 0; i < topics.length; i++) {
        var imAbutton = $("<button>");
        imAbutton.addClass("yup");
        imAbutton.attr("data-name", topics[i]);
        imAbutton.text(topics[i]);
        $(".buttonGallery").append(imAbutton);

    }};

buttonFactory();






 $("#anotherButton").on("click", function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();
        // This line grabs the input from the textbox
        var onemorebutton = $("#user-input").val().trim();
        // Adding movie from the textbox to our array
        topics.push(onemorebutton);
        // Calling renderButtons which handles the processing of our movie array
        buttonFactory();
      });


$(".yup").on("click", function(){
  

    
    $("#gif-Gallery").empty();
    var searchTermUpdate;
    var searchTerm = $(this).attr("data-name");
       // removing white space between two-word strings, replacing with a "+" \\
searchTermUpdate = searchTerm.replace(/ +/g, "+");

    var queryURL = "http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=" + searchTermUpdate + "&api_key=dc6zaTOxFJmzC&limit=10";
    $.ajax({
      url: queryURL,
      method: 'GET'
    }).done(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        
        var results = response.data;
 
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++){
          gifcount = gifLocation;
          
            
            var gifDIV = $("<div class='unit' data-state='still'>");
            var pRating = $("<p>").text("Rating: " + results[i].rating);
            var gifImg = $("<img id='gifimg' class='col-md-4'>");
            gifImg.attr("src", results[i].images.fixed_height_still.url);
            gifImg.attr({'data-animate' : results[i].images.fixed_height.url});
            gifImg.attr({'data-state' : "still"});
            gifImg.attr({'data-still' : results[i].images.fixed_height_still.url});
            gifDIV.append(pRating);
            gifDIV.append(gifImg);
            gifDIV.append(gifLocation);
            
           gifcount++;

          

            // appending gif div to DOM \\
            if (results[i].rating !== "g" || "pg" || "pg-13" || "y"){
            $("#gif-Gallery").append(gifDIV);
        }}

        $(".unit").on("click", function(){


                  var state = $(this).attr('data-state');
                  
                
                 if (state === "still") {
        $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("data-animate"));
        $(this).attr("data-state", "animate");
      } else {
        $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("data-still"));
        $(this).attr("data-state", "still");
      }
      

          
// var imgPath = this.children[1].src;
          
          clickCount++;
          var a;
          var b;
          var c;
          var d;
          var f;
          
                 
                  // if (clickCount % 2 === 0 ){
                  
                  //   for (i=0; i < imgPath.length; i++){
                  //     // locating index of underscore, storing that value in var a\\
                  //     var a = imgPath.indexOf("_");
                  //     // removing all characters to the right of the underscore \\
                  //     var b = imgPath.slice(0, a);
                  //      f = b;

                  //     // setting var c to a string value of .gif \\
                  //     var c = ".gif";
                  //     // combining var b and var c to complete updated image path \\
                  //     var d = b.concat(c);
                  //       }
                
                        // setting image url to animated url \\
                     // $(gifImg).attr("src", d);

                      
                     // this.children[1].src = d;
});
    });});            //
```

and here is the html if needed :

```html
<body>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="myHeader">
                <h1>WordSmiths</h1>
                <span class="text-muted" id="jtronText">
                    <div id="sometimeGone">Sometimes</div><div id="loadTimer">someone opens their mouth and you can't help but to be dazzled with the magic.</div>
                </span>
                <p class="text-success" id="instructionsOne">
                    Click a button, see what happens!
                </p>
                <p class="text-success" id="instructionsTwo">
                    Now you can create your own buttons!!!
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="buttonGallery"></div>
                <h4>Create buttons, find Gifs!: </h4>
                <form id="btnGeneratingForm">
                    <label for="input">Anything: </label>
                    <input type="text" id="user-input">
                    <br>
                    <input type="submit" id="anotherButton" value="More buttons">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div id="gif-Gallery"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

again, thanks in advance!
Robert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am actually doing the same project! I did it a pretty a similar way. I think the issue may be that you're appending the animated src to the image holder div instead of the child image itself. This line:
      $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("data-animate"));

Is what is giving you trouble I think.

Best of luck with the project, I hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, sir, thank you. Lol. I actually figured it out sometime last week, maybe should have updated this...whoops. Either way, thanks!

Comment: Ah perfect, glad to hear it! Best of luck.